# How to determine whether or not a point is in the first quadrant with a function in python

Tags: python, function, if-statement

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qiMlf.png)

Creating a function 'first' with input 'point' in x,y form test whether or not a point is in the first quadrant.

I am unable to get the variable 'point' into (x,y) form for the function 'first' to determine whether or not the point is in the first quadrant.

Comment: don't you mean `x, y = point`?
And *please* don't post code as a screenshot!!

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text. See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Change the problematic line as follows:

```
x,y = point
```

Comment: Not sure this kind of thing warrants an "answer" per-se...

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to comment. One point left...

Comment: Yeah, but your answer was already there in comment format before you posted...

Comment: Started answering before you posted